# GAE + Spring ASM Errors

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-security

I'm running into several error with the ASM class. The last one I was able to fix by including the a missing package in my POM. I'm stumped with this case, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is failing at my custom AuthenticationEntryPoint class, which extends AuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
public class TwitterAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,     AuthenticationException authException)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
    //UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();

    //System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
    //String login_url = userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI());
    //System.out.println(login_url);
    //response.sendRedirect(login_url);
      response.sendRedirect("/test");
  }
}
```

I have two questions I'm looking for an answer on:
1.) Is this type of error always caused by either a missing package or a version conflict?
2.) What am I missing in this case?

Stack Error:

```
[INFO] SEVERE: Unable to instrument com.hatraz.bucketlist.security.TwitterAuthenticationEntryPoint. Security restrictions may not be entirely emulated.
[INFO] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2629
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:2157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:542)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.rewrite(Transformer.java:146)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.impl.Transformer.transform(Transformer.java:113)
[INFO]  at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
[INFO]  at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
[INFO]  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[INFO]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
[INFO]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
[INFO]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[INFO]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1302)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.access$000(AbstractBeanFactory.java:109)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$4.run(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1268)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$4.run(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1266)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1266)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1350)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:355)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:326)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:249)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:306)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:88)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:254)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:212)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:210)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:210)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
```

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>bucket-list</groupId>
  <artifactId>bucket-list</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>GAE</id>
      <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <directory>war</directory>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>war/WEB-INF</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>            
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <!--  <webXml>war/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>  -->
            <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
            <webResources>
                <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/war/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/war/pages</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <targetPath>pages</targetPath>
                </resource>


            </webResources>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.8</version>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
  <dependencies>         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>[3.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-PFD2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-endpoints-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>      
  </dependencies>
</project>
```